# for /f %a in (Y:\el.txt) do move %a C:\Users\srinu\Desktop\test

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am run below cmds in commands prompt
for Ex:

```
for /f %a in (Y:\el.txt) do move %a C:\Users\srinu\Desktop\test
```

after that i need result txt file
Example:c:\skipped.txt (not moved File Numbers) how to create in cmd
how to write in command prompt

Comment: it's the same command, just change `%a` to `%%a` in batch file, also you can redirect the output (all of it, not just the skipped ones) to a file using the `>>` operator so your command becomes `for /f %%a in ([SRC]) do move %%a [DIST] >> 'LOG'`

Comment: i tryed but not working.

Comment: sentences like 'it didn't work' and 'not working' doesn't give the others any information at all, can you please specify what you used (a sample of code) and what the result/error was

Comment: i am getting syntax error

Comment: @srinuu: What is the command you entered based on what tbc wrote? Did you include [SRC] and [DIST] as-is?

Comment: below batch file i  used its working fine but it not showing fille numbers.please find reference,
         1 file(s) moved.  for ex:56786 file moved i need this information
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.

Answer (score 0):

here is the command for cmd:

```
for /f %a in (Y:\el.txt) do move "%a" "C:\Users\srinu\Desktop\test"
```

in a batch file:

```
for /f %%a in (Y:\el.txt) do @move "%%a" "C:\Users\srinu\Desktop\test" >> log.txt
```